# AngularJS updating custom directive variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one variable in my controller used as flag. i use this variable in directives scope. i call my controller function from directive (passing directive scope with this function) and try to update flag variable, variable is update in controller(got updated value in console.log()) but i am not getting updated value inside directive.

Comment: Please copy your code here or on jsfiddle. Also what is the scope object value in your directive.

Answer (score 0):

Need your code to know what's the relationship between your directive and controller.
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOuaZNN3LzWBdQ7SuPns?p=preview) is my simple example. $scope.test can be updated.

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.test='msg from myCtrl';
  $scope.onClick=function(){
    $scope.test='msg from function in myCtrl';
  };


}]);

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<div>Hello! {{test}}</div><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click=onClick()>Change value</button>',
    controller:['$scope','$element',function($scope, $element){
      $scope.test='msg from myDirective controller.'
    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

    },
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  {{test}}<br/>
  <my-directive />
</div>
</body>
```